# How to query a stored procedure to parent and child tables?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table of jobs and a stored procedure to show that jobs per user.
But now, I need to use a different query for the same column.

For now I got this:

```
SELECT 
    extrajobs.ExtraJobsID, prof.ProfileName, 
    functscope.Name AS functionscope1, 
    functscope.Name AS functionscope2, 
    extrajobs.FunctionScopeID, 
    users.UserID, extrajobs.CreateDate, 
    users.Username, extrajobs.LastUpdate, 
    prof.ProfileName, 
    extrajobs.Description, extrajobs.Day, extrajobs.Hours, 
    extrajobs.Remaining, extrajobs.Coordinator, 
    extrajobs.Feedback__On_Coordinator, extrajobs.Status_Coordinator, 
    extrajobs.Director, extrajobs.Status_Director, 
    extrajobs.Feedback__On_Director
    --SELECT DISTINCT(users.Username), prof.ProfileName
FROM 
    TBL_User AS users
JOIN 
    TBL_ExtraJobs AS extrajobs ON extrajobs.UserID = users.UserID
JOIN
    TBL_UserFunctionScope AS functscope ON extrajobs.FunctionScopeID= functscope.FunctionScopeID
JOIN
    REL_ProfileUser AS relprofileuser ON users.UserID = relprofileuser.UserID
JOIN
    TBL_Profile AS prof ON prof.ProfileID = relprofileuser.ProfileID
JOIN
    TBL_UserFunction AS funct ON funct.FunctionID = relprofileuser.FunctionID
WHERE 
    funct.Name = 'Extra-jobs'
```

[Stored procedure result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UusOt.png)

and this is table of jobs:

[TBL_FunctionScope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH4us.png)

And now, in the result from the stored procedure, I want to put int functioscope1 the parent of funtionscope2 like the `TBL_FunctionScope`.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need is to include JOINs with the TBL_FunctionScope and TBL_UserFunctionScope, like this:

```
SELECT 
    extrajobs.ExtraJobsID, prof.ProfileName, 
    functscope.Name AS functionscope1, 
    functscope.Name AS functionscope2, 
    parentfunctscope.Name as parentfunction,
    extrajobs.FunctionScopeID, 
    users.UserID, extrajobs.CreateDate, 
    users.Username, extrajobs.LastUpdate, 
    prof.ProfileName, 
    extrajobs.Description, extrajobs.Day, extrajobs.Hours, 
    extrajobs.Remaining, extrajobs.Coordinator, 
    extrajobs.Feedback__On_Coordinator, extrajobs.Status_Coordinator, 
    extrajobs.Director, extrajobs.Status_Director, 
    extrajobs.Feedback__On_Director
    --SELECT DISTINCT(users.Username), prof.ProfileName
FROM 
    TBL_User AS users
JOIN 
    TBL_ExtraJobs AS extrajobs ON extrajobs.UserID = users.UserID
JOIN
    TBL_UserFunctionScope AS functscope ON extrajobs.FunctionScopeID= functscope.FunctionScopeID
JOIN
    TBL_FunctionScope as func ON extrajobs.FunctionScopeID= func.FunctionScopeID
LEFT JOIN
    TBL_UserFunctionScope AS parentfunctscope ON func.ParentScopeID = parentfunctscope.FunctionScopeID
JOIN
    REL_ProfileUser AS relprofileuser ON users.UserID = relprofileuser.UserID
JOIN
    TBL_Profile AS prof ON prof.ProfileID = relprofileuser.ProfileID
JOIN
    TBL_UserFunction AS funct ON funct.FunctionID = relprofileuser.FunctionID
WHERE 
    funct.Name = 'Extra-jobs'
```